# Pattern for last occurring element

Tags: java, android, regex, recursion

so I recently wrote a piece of regex like this:

```
replaceInputWithLatex("sinus(?<formula>.*?)moveout",
    "\\\\sin(${formula})");

replaceInputWithLatex("sinus(?<formula>.+)",
    "\\\\sin" + changeColorOfString("Red", "(") + "${formula}" + changeColorOfString("Red", ")"));

replaceInputWithLatex("sinus",
    "\\\\sin" + noInputBox);
```

Here's replaceInputWithLatex function:

```
private static void replaceInputWithLatex(String pattern, String latexOutput{
    regexPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(mathFormula);

    while(regexMatcher.find()){
        Log.d("FOUND", regexMatcher.group());

        mathFormula = regexMatcher.replaceAll(latexOutput);
        replaceInputWithLatex(pattern, latexOutput);
    }
}
```

Let's say I input a string: "sinus1+sinus2x+3moveout".

I would like the 1st match to take this string: "sinus2x+3moveout". And replace it. And in the next iteration match "sinus1+(already_converted)".

However, so far it takes an entire string first. Here are "FOUND" logs:

```
11-12 19:26:40.750 30244-30244/com.example.user.signum D/FOUND: sinus1+sinus2x+3moveout
11-12 19:26:40.750 30244-30244/com.example.user.signum D/FOUND: sinus2x+3
```

Latex output look like this(I want both outside parentheses to be red - in reverse order as it is now):

[image]

What pattern shall I use? (I've been trying recursive approach, but I haven't come up with a solution yet)

Comment: Could you set red color on the first one `sinus(?<formula>.*?)moveout` instead?

Comment: No, I can't. In short I just want the regex to parse always last occurance of pattern 1st. Like from right side to left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mocked up a working example in JavaScript.

Basically, we keep hitting the input with the same regex. We mark the tail end we've already handled with some special characters, then handle the next one to the left, and so on. When the markers cover the whole string, we're done.

```js
console.clear();
var input = "sinus1+sinus2x+3moveout";
do {
  console.log(input);
  input = input.replace(/(sinus\dx?\+)?(?:\d?moveout|(<<handled>>))$/, function(m,lead){
    return lead ? "<<handled>>" : "{{all done}}"
  });
} while (input.indexOf("<<") !== -1);
console.log(input);
```

It's a bit pseudo-codey, but I hope this gives you some useful ideas.